# Explode a DataFrame of array<array<string>> created from json and add headers

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

So I have json data of School students' count as follows.The data entries are more , I have posted only two here.

```
{"fields":[
         {"id":"a","label":"Particulars","type":"string"},
         {"id":"b","label":"State","type":"string"},
         {"id":"c","label":"Gender","type":"string"},
         {"id":"d","label":"2001","type":"string"},
         {"id":"e","label":"2002","type":"string"},
         {"id":"f","label":"2003","type":"string"},
         ],
 "data":[
        ["Secondary School","Andhra Pradesh","Girl","1081706","1234920","1378977"],
        ["Secondary School","Assam","Boy","922535","690086","966831"],
        ]}
```

So here is my code to read from json file.The data column has only one entry which is array<array<String>>. So i want to explode the array and create multiple entries with multiple columns.

```
val schoolText = sqlContext.read.json("/home/onkar/DRIVE(C)/zeppelin_try_code/data.json")
schoolText.printSchema()
val data=schoolText.select("data")
data.printSchema()
data.registerTempTable("data")

---Output-----
schoolText: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [data: array<array<string>>,
fields: array<struct<id:string,label:string,type:string>>]
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- fields: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [data: array<array<string>>]
root
|-- data: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I have tried explode() function and DataFrame.withCoumn() but couldn't do.
Please help.

Comment: And what would be the output?

Comment: did you solve this or do you still need help with this?